# Prove that if $n \mid 10^n-1$ then $3 \mid n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove that if $n \mid 10^n-1$ then $3 \mid n$ for $n>1$.

So far I have let $p \mid n$. Hence $10^n \equiv 1\mod{p}$, and, from Fermat's Little Theorem, $10^{p-1} \equiv 1\mod{p}$.

Comment: If I take $n=1$, then $1 | 10^1 - 1 = 9$, but not $3|n=1$. Are you sure that the task is correctly formulated?

Comment: according to @ml4294 comment i pressume that $n>1$

Comment: @ml4294 Edited accordingly

Comment: For Plato, a number was a proper multiple of 1.

Comment: As a comment on the existence of $n$, it can be show that $n=111$ is the smallest positive integer which is not a power of $3$ and satisfies the condition.  In fact, if $p>3$ is a prime factor of $10^{3^k}-1$, then all integers of the form $3^{k+l}\cdot p$ for integers $l\geq0$ satisfy the required condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $p$ be the smallest prime such that $p|n$.

(**edit:** Note that $2|n$ and $5|n$ are impossible, so $p\neq 2$ and $p\neq 5$.)

Let $a>0$ be the smallest integer such that $10^a \equiv 1 \mod p$.
Because of $10^n \equiv 1 \mod p$ it can be shown that $a|n$.

Suppose $a=1$, then it follows $p=3$ and we are done.

Since $10^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$ we know that $a<p$.

So we have $1<a<p$ and $a|n$, which is a contradiction to $p$ being the smallest prime that divides $n$.

Comment: @BillDubuque I edited my answer to adress your criticism and the cases $p=2,5$. My initial answer was not aimed at absolute beginners, i rather chose a mathematical level of detail such that OP would understand it (this is my usual approach on MSE).

Comment: To clarify for those who missed the long (now deleted) comment discussion: the critique was due to another user (I merely responded in support, and made it more precise).

Comment: For the record, the prior comment discussion has been [preserved here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/803858e4-19cd-4135-a22d-27630aab6016/view-source) (they should have been moved to chat instead of censored). A couple final comments are missing (weren't in the cache).

Comment: Also, I'd be grateful if you could please explain why you downvoted my answer, since that may allow me to improve the answer by addressing  whatever issue you observed.

Answer (score 2):

$p := $ $\rm\color{#0a0}{least}$ prime factor of $n$. $\,p\mid n\mid 10^{\large n}\!-\!1\Rightarrow p\nmid 10,\,$ so by Fermat ${\rm mod}\ p\!:\, 10^{\large p-1}\!\equiv 1\equiv 10^{\large n}\,$ thus $10$ has order $j$ dividing  $\rm\color{#0a0}{coprimes}$ $\,p\!-\!1$ and $\,n,\,$ so $\,j=\color{#c00}{\bf 1}\,$ so $\,p\mid 10^{\color{#c00}{\bf 1}}\!-1\,\Rightarrow\,p=3$

Comment: I think it’s quite improper to downvote an answer without giving a justification via comment.

Comment: @Lubin Thanks for the upvote and support. I do always encourage downvoters to share any constructive criticism since it can often lead to nontrivial improvements to answers. Lacking such (as here), it is often difficult or impossible to infer what proved problematic to the downvoter..